# What is the code within the choice command

Tags: windows, batch-file

That title may be a bit confusing, so let me elaborate. I want to know what the code is behind the choice command. There is not really much reason other than curiosity and the fact that it might help me one day. I've searched everywhere but can't find it.

I don't know much about open source projects and the like, but may it be because Windows doesn't want people to know (or for it to be easily accessible)?

Any information will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mahmoud Al-Qudsi pointed out, Windows is not open source. FreeDOS however is, and the choice command is available [here](http://www.freedos.org/software/?prog=choice).

Comment: I already have the choice command, I'm just intrigued about how it works. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Yes, and FreeDOS's version is open source, so you can look at the code and find out how it works.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's in an executable file, and I can't read them. Sorry if I'm being a hassle, but I'm just not that smart.

Comment: [http://winsupport.org/packages/choice43a.zip](http://winsupport.org/packages/choice43a.zip) direct link to source.

Answer (score 2):

Windows is not open source. The code for *any* Windows command-line utilities is not routinely released. This has nothing to do with Microsoft especially not wanting you to know how `choice` in particular is implemented!

That said, [it looks to be very straight-forward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choice_%28command%29). Implementation would be a dozen lines or so at most.. what part of it is giving you trouble?

Comment: It's not so much that it's giving me trouble. It's more about me not being able to think how it can take the input automatically, unlike set (with the /p switch) which waits for the enter key to be set. Oh, and I wasn't trying to make it seem as if I think Windows is bad for not releasing it, I just didn't know how to phrase it properly.